# Excel 2007 VBA Userform Preview HTML

Tags: excel, vba

I've got an Excel userform that stores HTML in a textbox, and I'd like to preview that HTML rendered within the userform. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not have a copy of Excel 2007 immediately available, but you should be able to find the Microsoft Web Browser control in Additional Controls on the Developer tab. You can then add it to your form. You can save the HTML to a temporary file (the FileSystemObject may suit) and use the Web Browser control to navigate to the file, it can then be displayed.

```
strLink = "c:\docs\default.html"
Me.WebBrowser1.Navigate strLink
```